# Проблема со связями

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

У меня есть два типа юзеров: Админ и Сотрудник.
Админ имеет много организаций, а сотрудник принадлжет к организации

Когда я создаю админа то rails просит чтобы он принадлежал к организации. Хотя он не должен принадлежать им.
Как сделать так чтобы юзер принадлежаал к организации, а админ нет.
Пока у меня как-то так.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Я просто добавил в модель User

```
belongs_to: organization, optional: true
```

И это решило проблему